# text position moves with different resolution

Tags: css, position, screen-resolution

I was wondering if someone can help me?? I'm a super novice with CSS and HTML and the CSS below looks good on a 1280 X 800 screen size but anything smaller or larger, the position moves position. How can I fix this? I've tried positioning it "fix" and "relative" and it failed to work. Thanks in advance!!

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 230px;
height: auto;
text-align: right;
position: absolute;
top: 62px;
right: 180px;
float:right;
clear:both;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its main container and  looks like you have design the website on 1280 X 800 resolution .you have set the position by    `top: 62px;   right: 180px;`

dont do that because it will only work on the 1280 X 800 if you want to work on all make a container and make it on the center by `margin:0 auto;` and than make all design on that so it will always in the center

if its not main container than please let me know

Comment: Thanks for the tip! it works now because I realized it was not in the main container :D

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand you correctly, but a quick hack could be to specify a fixed width for the body. Example:

```
body {
    width: 1280px;
}
```